# Can f not be in L1 if its Fourier transform is in L-infinity?

Tags: real-analysis

Can $f\notin L^1$ if its Fourier transform $\hat f \in L^\infty$  ?

This is a question about the endpoint of Pontryagin duality.  We know that if a function is in $L^1$, then its Fourier transform lies in $L^\infty$. This is very easy to show.  But what about the converse: Can the $L^1$ norm of $f$ be infinite even if the $L^\infty$ norm of its Fourier transform is finite?

I assume that the answer to my question is YES, but I do not see how to handle this case. Any references?

Comment: How is the Fourier transform $\hat f$ of $f$ even defined, when $f$ is not $\in L^1$?

Comment: assuming that the Fourier transform of $f$ is well-defined to begin with?

Comment: Define $f$ as the inverse transform of an $L^\infty$ function $\hat f$.  For example, let $\hat f$ be 1 in the interval [-1,1] and zero outside.  What happens? I need some help to understand such cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Fourier transform of the characteristic function of $[-1,1]$ is $\sin(\xi)/\xi$ (times a constant which depends on conventions), which is certainly not in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: But there is a delicate point here.  $\sin(\xi)/\xi$ is not Lebesgue integrable, so its Fourier transform is only defined as a limit of $L^1$ functions. Of course, the OP must have considered this since the question specifically asks about the Fourier Transform a function not in $L^1$.

Comment: In any case, your counterexample is the one I thought of when I read the question. (+1)

Comment: Excellent.  I will consider the question answered. I am very grateful to these comments because as a physicist, my math training was not rigorous enough.

Answer (score 0):

When we **do not** take distribution theory (i.e., the dirac delta functional) into consideration, we have a constant function as a counter-example, which is in $L^\infty$, but not a Fourier transform of a certain $L^1$ function.